# Spock believes inner enum of tested class should be a property of Spec

Tags: java, groovy, enums, spock

I have a Java class that I'm trying to test with Spock. The Java class contains an inner enum:

```
import static java.util.Calendar.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FederalHolidays {

    public enum Observance {
        NEW_YEARS_DAY(JANUARY, 1),
        BIRTHDAY_OF_MARTIN_LUTHER_KING_JR(JANUARY, MONDAY, 3),
        WASHINGTONS_BIRTHDAY(FEBRUARY, MONDAY, 3),
        MEMORIAL_DAY(MAY, MONDAY, -1),
        INDEPENDENCE_DAY(JULY, 4),
        LABOR_DAY(SEPTEMBER, MONDAY, 1),
        COLUMBUS_DAY(OCTOBER, MONDAY, 2),
        VETERANS_DAY(NOVEMBER, 11),
        THANKSGIVING_DAY(NOVEMBER, THURSDAY, 4),
        CHIRSTMAS_DAY(DECEMBER, 25);

        private final int month;
        private final int dayOfMonth;
        private final int dayOfWeek;
        private final int weekOfMonth;
        private static final int NA = 0;

        private Observance(int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            this.month = month;
            this.dayOfMonth = dayOfMonth;
            this.dayOfWeek = NA;
            this.weekOfMonth = NA;
        }

        private Observance(int month, int dayOfWeek, int weekOfMonth) {
            this.month = month;
            this.dayOfMonth = NA;
            this.dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek;
            this.weekOfMonth = weekOfMonth;
        }

        boolean isFixedDate() {
            return dayOfMonth != NA;
        }
    }

    public Date dateOf(Observance observance, int year) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"), Locale.ENGLISH);
        cal.set(YEAR, year);
        cal.set(MONTH, observance.month);
        cal.clear(HOUR);
        if (observance.isFixedDate()) {
            cal.set(DAY_OF_MONTH, observance.dayOfMonth);
        } else {
            setNthDayOfWeek(cal, observance.dayOfWeek, observance.weekOfMonth);
        }
        adjustForWeekendsIfNecessary(cal);
        return cal.getTime();
    }

    private void setNthDayOfWeek(Calendar cal, int dayOfWeek, int n) {
        int week = 0;
        int lastDay = cal.getActualMaximum(DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int startDay = n > 0 ? 1 : lastDay;
        int endDay = n > 0 ? lastDay : 1;
        int incrementValue = n > 0 ? 1 : -1;
        for (int day = startDay; day != endDay; day += incrementValue) {
            cal.set(DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
            if (cal.get(DAY_OF_WEEK) == dayOfWeek) {
                week += incrementValue;
                if (week == n) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void adjustForWeekendsIfNecessary(Calendar cal) {
        int dayOfWeek = cal.get(DAY_OF_WEEK);
        cal.add(DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfWeek == SATURDAY ? -1 : dayOfWeek == SUNDAY ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
```

My Spock test spec looks like this:

```
 class FederalHolidaysSpec extends Specification {

    @Shared
    def federalHolidays = new FederalHolidays()

    def "holidays are correctly calculated"() {
        expect:
            federalHolidays.dateOf(observance, year).format('yyyy/MM/dd') == date
        where:
            observance                        | year | date
            NEW_YEARS_DAY                     | 2011 | '2010/12/31'
            BIRTHDAY_OF_MARTIN_LUTHER_KING_JR | 2011 | '2011/01/17'
            WASHINGTONS_BIRTHDAY              | 2011 | '2011/02/21'
            MEMORIAL_DAY                      | 2011 | '2011/05/30'
            INDEPENDENCE_DAY                  | 2011 | '2011/07/04'
            LABOR_DAY                         | 2011 | '2011/09/05'
            COLUMBUS_DAY                      | 2011 | '2011/10/10'
            VETERANS_DAY                      | 2011 | '2011/11/11'
            THANKSGIVING_DAY                  | 2011 | '2011/11/24'
            CHIRSTMAS_DAY                     | 2011 | '2011/12/26'
    }
}
```

When I run Spock, I get 10 test errors, one per each row of the table. Every error is identical:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Observance for class:   bdkosher.FederalHolidaysSpec
    at bdkosher.FederalHolidaysSpec.$spock_initializeFields(FederalHolidaysSpec.groovy)
```

(I'm using Spock 0.7-groovy-2.0, groovy-all 2.2.2 (non-indy), and Java 1.7.0_45.)

**Why is Spock looking for a property named Observance on my FederalHolidaysSpec class?**
I initially suspected the issue was related to inner enums/static imports, although changing my Spock test to use fully qualified enum values (e.g. bdkosher.FederalHolidays.Observance.CHRISTMAS_DAY) did not make a difference.

*EDIT: Java file implementation corrected so it passes test; typos corrected in test file.*

Comment: Doesn't the `enum` have to be public as well?

Comment: Yes, good catch (I hadn't tried using the API outside of its package yet). But even when I put the `public` modifier on it, I still get the  same test errors.

Comment: @BDKosher I checked your code. It works for me. My setup: groovy *2.2.1*, spock *0.7-groovy-2.0*. Apart from multiple typos and 2 miscalculated dates, all runs smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have correct packages for both the source code and the test case. Below works for me if both the java class and the test class are in the same package.

```
package bdkosher

import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification
//import bdkosher.FederalHolidays.Observance //Do not need
import static bdkosher.FederalHolidays.Observance.*

class FederalHolidaysSpec extends Specification { .. }
```

I tested without a default package name as `com.example` and in a Grails app although the spock version was same.

Answer (score 0):

After hearing of @elems' and @dmahaptro's successes, I started ripping things out of my project structure and reducing down dependencies in my POM.

After dropping the unused `src/test/java` and `src/main/groovy` directories entirely, I noticed the  `FederalHolidaysSpec.groovy` source file in my IDE reverted to an older version (I'm not sure if I should blame `gmavenplus-plugin` or NetBeans for this--I'm suspecting the later since I was consistently testing using `mvn clean test`). In any case, this older version contained an additional field:

```
class FederalHolidaysSpec extends Specification {

    def data = [(Observance.NEW_YEARS_DAY) : ['2011/12/31']]
```

This field was causing the test errors. Even with an `import bdkosher.FederalHolidays.Observance`, Groovy apparently believes the map key to be a property reference rather than a `enum` reference?

In any case, now I can fix the typos and legitimate test failures. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if Groovy supports importing a nested class.

Comment: It looks to be that way. Using the FQN-- `def data = [(gov.uspto.trademark.tmng.datetime.FederalHolidays.Observance.NEW_YEARS_DAY) : ['2011/12/31']]` --does not cause any errors. The static import works as I intend, at least.

Comment: `import gov.uspto.trademark.tmng.datetime.FederalHolidays` and `(FederalHolidays.Observance.NEW_YEARS_DAY)` will probably work as well.

Comment: Yes, that works. If I `import gov.uspto.trademark.tmng.datetime.FederalHolidays.Observance` and define a field `def newYears = Observance.NEW_YEARS_DAY`, Groovy has no complaints. It must just be problematic when using it as a Map key.